# How to get a diagram of a database on Azure sql on MacBook

Tags: sql, azure, macos, diagram

I'm totally new in SQL and trying to find a way to get the diagram of a database. As most of you know it's just a right click for windows user. However it's a bit difficult for MAC&Azure users (at least for me). I can get a schema through database >> manage >> schema visualisation, but it's not as good as the diagrams on windows and I can't extract it most of the times due to the various errors! So, are there any free extension or other ways that I can use to see the primary keys and the ties between tables? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **JetBrains DataGrip** tool to create database diagrams. DataGrip is a SQL server GUI tool for Windows, **macOS**, Linux. To generate a database diagram in DataGrip,

- Right click database object in the database explorer.
- Select diagrams -> Show visualization

[image]

**Image Reference:** [Database diagrams | DataGrip Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/creating-diagrams.html#db_diagrams)